# Post text input before submit action working inconsistently

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I'm trying to create a consent form, and having the user input their name. When the submit button is pressed, I post their text input to a PHP file which mails their name to me (I understand that there are easier ways to do this). However this form works inconsistently; sometimes it records the user's name and sometimes it doesn't. On my computer it usually always works so I have trouble troubleshooting the problem.

here's the code:

```
//submitlink is a dummy link
$("#submitlink").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name1val = $("#name1").val();
    if (!(name1val == '')){
        $.post("mail.php",
               { name : name1val, time : curr_time} 
        );
        //agree is a <form id="agree" action="nextpage.php">
        $("#agree").submit();
    else{
       //display error message
    }
 }
```

and mail.php is:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $name . " has begun the survey at " . date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$result = mail('myemail', 'User has begun survey', $text);
?>
```

Can you think of reasons why this code would fail to work? How can I be sure to post data reliably after the user clicks a submit button?

Comment: You're missing a closing brackets and parenthesis for one. Where's the `if (name1val !== '')` closing bracket? What about the `.click(function() {...})`?

Comment: Sorry - the closing brackets are there in the correct code. I copied and pasted the relevant parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're submitting the second form `$("#agree").submit();` before confirming that the AJAX call has succeeded. Sometimes this will work; often it won't.  Put the `submit` call in a success handler:

```
$.post("mail.php",
    { name : name1val, time : curr_time},
    function(){
        $("#agree").submit();
    }
);
```

This will call the code after the AJAX request has completed.